# Как подойти к разработке админ панели?

Tags: веб-программирование, cms

Хотелось бы узнать как называется специалист который разрабатывает панели управления для сайта? Хочу по этому вопросу больше почитать, есть представление конечно, как это реализовать В ОБЩЕМ, но тонкостей я не знаю.. Боюсь вот чего: то что моя неопытность в этом вопросе приведёт к постоянному переписыванию кода. А мне бы хотелось уже сейчас решить многие вопросы и заложить фундамент для гибкой системы управления... Может кто-то встречал книгу по такому вопросу? Заранее благодарен за ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Я бы порекомендовал вам начать с изучения какого-либо популярного фреймворка. Фреймворк - это набор готовых библиотек и стратегия по их использованию, помогающая сформировать каркас нужного приложения. В PHP самые популярные фреймоворки - это Yii 2, Laravel, Symfony. Все они имеют отличную документацию с прекрасными примерами кода, позволяющими написать любой сайт, так же к ним есть множество готовых расширений, реализующих панели управления сайтами  и инструкции по созданию своих собственных панелей.

Если же вы вообще не умеет программировать в вебе, то начинать нужно с изучения языка, под веб заточенного - PHP, Go,  javascript (node.js), Python и т. д. Языков очень много, но я бы рекомендовал начать с PHP - он наиболее просто и легок в изучении, а может то же самое, что и все остальные.

Для совсем новичков рекомендую этот курс - http://www.kurepin.ru/php/

Answer (score 0):

Панели управления сайтами - Они же CMS. Пишется все это очень просто. Необходимо хорошо знать один из этих языков и фреймворки для них: Php, python, js , java и т.д
Начиная программировать , уже начинаешь понимать как все работает. Эти запросы в базу данных, сохранение данных и соответственно вывод. Т.е дописывается сам код, но что бы человек не шарился в чужом коде или он ее умеет програмировать, создают панели управления (CMS). Например Worldpress, Joomla!
Человек хочет вести свой сайт-блог, хоп и готово. И никакие знания в области веб разработки не нужны.